# Get accurate ELF dependencies

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, elf, ldd

I know two ways to find dependencies,
`ldd app.out` which returns this for a simple app:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffff93f5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f02383a0000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0238800000)
```

and `readelf -d app.out | grep NEEDED` which returns:

```
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

I want to understand why is output difference, `libc.so` is in both cases, `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is interpreter and makes sense to be in the first one, but about about `linux-vdso.so.1`? and which one is more accurate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`readelf -d` shows what the app wants, `ldd` shows what the linker wants.

They're different because:

- `ldd` shows the transitive closure of dependencies (i.e. recursively), while `readelf` only shows the immediate dependencies
- `ldd` shows the loader, which `readelf` considers seperate from a dynamic dependency
- `ldd` shows virtual libraries, which are a system implementation detail that the app doesn't care about

This means that which is more accurate is up to you and your use case.

If you are creating a VM image and need to copy all dependencies, you would use `ldd` because it determines what the current system needs to run the app. If you are writing a compatibility layer like `wine`, you would use `readelf` because it determines what the app needs from the host system.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer